# user can not sign because there’s no URL created and sent to us from Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

We are receiving the following error when I try to create a recipient view. Basically the document is sent to 2 users, one of them has already signed but the other user can not sign because there’s no URL created and sent to us from Docusign. We are using node.js docusign sdk.

```
var recipientView = new docusign.RecipientViewRequest();
recipientView.setReturnUrl();
recipientView.setUserName();
recipientView.setEmail(;
recipientView.setAuthenticationMethod("email");
recipientView.setClientUserId();

var envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();
envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelope.id, recipientView,
    function(error, viewUrl, response) {
    // no url is returned here.the error (in the image) is shown
});
```

I printed the values of accountId, envelopeId and those seemed to be fine.I checked if the user had changed his first name, last name and there were no errors there. If I create a new user from scratch everything works fine.

- FrontEnd Error
  [image]
- Response Error
  [image]

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? There is no image in your post.

Comment: I jsut added them.

Answer (score 4):

Through your screenshots it looks like you are getting an `UKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT` error returned from the API.  This means the recipient data you are sending to identify the recipient is not correct.  It needs to exactly match the data you assigned to the recipient when you added them to the envelope, such as `name`, `email`, `recipientId`, and `clientUserId`.

Try calling the [EnvelopeRecipients: List](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) API before you make the request to generate the URL and ensure that the recipient data matches what you are sending in your `createRecipientView()` request. That should help identify which piece of data is off, once you correct that the call will then start returning the proper URL.

Also see the [Embedded Signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning) features page in the DocuSign Developer Center which shows exactly which params you need to set etc: